# Upload Images, Videos to Node.js WebService and store in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: node.js, azure, blob

I have created a Node.js Webservice which takes Json object in the post body and in the same object I need to pass the image/video (not sure whether its possible) media files and the same media file needs to up uploaded to Azure Blob Storage.

Azure storage gives library where we upload the stream. But how do I upload the files to node.js server from Apps before uploading to Azure blob storage.

The concept has to work on Windows, Android and IOS platform.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is hosted on Web apps and assuming it’s built by expressjs, @Alex Lau provided a good point.

Also, here are another 2 libs for express handling upload files. I’d like to give you some code snippets to handle upload files and put to blob storage in expressjs with these libs:

1,[connect-busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy)

```
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var fs = require('fs'); 
var path = require('path');
var blobsrv = azure.createBlobService(
    accountname,
    accountkey
)

router.post('/file', function (req, res, next) {
   var fstream;
    var uploadfolder = path.join(__dirname, '../files/');
   if (mkdirsSync(uploadfolder)) {
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
           console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
            fstream = fs.createWriteStream(uploadfolder + filename);
            file.pipe(fstream);
            fstream.on('close', function () {
                //res.redirect('back');
                blobsrv.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('mycontainer',filename,uploadfolder + filename, function (error, result, response) {
                    if (!error) {
                        res.send(200, 'upload succeeded');
                    } else {
                        res.send(500, 'error');
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    }
})

function mkdirsSync(dirpath, mode) {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dirpath)) {
        var pathtmp;
        dirpath.split("\\").forEach(function (dirname) {
            console.log(dirname);
            if (pathtmp) {
                pathtmp = path.join(pathtmp, dirname);
            }
            else {
                pathtmp = dirname;
            }
            if (!fs.existsSync(pathtmp)) {
                if (!fs.mkdirSync(pathtmp, mode)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}
```

2,[formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable)

```
var formidable = require('formidable')
router.post('/fileform', function (req, res, next) {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.onPart = function (part){
        part.on('data', function (data){
            console.log(data);
            var bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
            bufferStream.end(data);
            blobsrv.createBlockBlobFromStream('mycontainer', part.filename, bufferStream, data.length, function (error, result, response){
                if (!error) {
                    res.send(200,'upload succeeded')
                } else {
                    res.send(500,JSON.stringify(error))
                }
            })
        })
   }
    form.parse(req);
    //res.send('OK');
})
```

If you are using a Mobile Apps with Node.js as a backend to handle these workflows, we can create a custom API, and transfer media content in base64 code.

In mobile app:

```
var azure = require('azure');
var fs = require('fs');   
var path = require('path');
exports.register = function (api) {
        api.post('upload',upload);
}
function upload(req,res){
        var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(
            req.service.config.appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNTNAME,
            req.service.config.appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNTKEY
        );
        var decodedImage = new Buffer(req.body.imgdata, 'base64');
        var tmpfilename = (new Date()).getTime()+'.jpg';
        var tmpupload = 'upload/';
        mkdirsSync(tmpupload);
        var filePath = tmpupload+tmpfilename;
        fs.writeFileSync(filePath,decodedImage); blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromFile(req.body.container,tmpfilename,filePath,req.body.option,function(error,result,response){
            if(!error){
                res.send(200,{result:true});
            }else{
                res.send(500,{result:error});
            }
        })
}
```

In mobile application, I used iconic framework integrated ng-cordova plugin to handle camera events.
Here are controller and server script snippet. For your information:

Controller js:

```
$scope.getpic = function(){
    var options = {
      quality: 10,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: false,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };
    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      console.log(imageData);
      return blobService.uploadBlob(objectId,imageData);
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    }).then(function(res){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    });
  };
```

Server js(blobService):

```
factory('blobService',function($q){
       return{
              uploadBlob:function(container,imgdata,option){
                     var q = $q.defer();
                     mobileServiceClient.invokeApi('blobstorage/upload',{
                           method:"post",
                           body:{
                                  container:container,
                                  imgdata:imgdata,
                                  option:{contentType:'image/jpeg'}
                           }
                     }).done(function(res){
                           console.log(JSON.stringify(res.result));
                           if(res.result.blob !== undefined){
                                  q.resolve(res.result.blob);
                           }
                           if(res.result.url !== undefined){
                                  q.resolve(res.result.url);
                           }
                     });                  
                     return q.promise;
              }
       }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may consider using `multipart/form-data` instead of JSON as there is a good library ([expressjs/multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), assuming you are using `express`) to handle file uploading in node.js.

As long as you get the file from multer, the rest can be very simple as below:

```
app.post('/profile', upload.single('avatar'), function (req, res, next) {
    blobService.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('avatars', req.file.originalname, req.file.path, function(error, result, response) {
    });
});
```

---

For iOS and Android, there are also plenty of libraries that allow `multipart/form-data` request like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) in iOS and [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) in Android.

Comment: I tried uploading image and video it works but is it possible to send both media files and data may be in string format or directly json in the same request

Comment: You may but then you have to encode them in base64, which costs extra development effort, network bandwidth and computing time.

Comment: I tried using the concept shown below tried it out in fiddler which is working for both data and multiple images. So is it fine to use it....


---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"; filename="31 august 2015.png"
Content-Type: image/png

<@INCLUDE *C:\2015.png*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jsondata"
Content-Type: application/json

{ "name" : "some name", "age" : 24, "dob" : "15/April/1989" }
---------------------------acebdf13572468--